# Building a column of values based on a formula in R

Tags: r

I want to create a column of length nr (from nrow of a separate data frame), filled with gradually increasing values based on E and an integer f.  For the first row I want 0 (E*0), the next one should be 1.655 (E*1), next 3.311 (E*2), all the way until the number of rows is equal to nr.
The best way I can think of to describe what I want to do borrows from my experience programming my calculator:

(nr and E are previously-calculated values)

```
f <- 0
Lbl A
(new value to go into a new row in the same column) <- E*f
If f<nr
f <- f+1
Goto A
Else
Break
##pair this column with another column named "G" in a new data frame
##save a csv file of this new data frame
```

The idea being that if the integer f gets to the same value as nr, the loop will break.  It seems like an easy enough idea to execute, but I still don't know most basic functions in R.

Comment: Could you tell us what is E in your code?

Comment: @Metrics: I guess E is basically 1.655

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
E*seq(0,nr,1)
```

If `nr=10`:

```
> 1.655*seq(0,nr-1,1)
 [1]  0.000  1.655  3.310  4.965  6.620  8.275  9.930 11.585 13.240 14.895
```

Answer (score 2):

When using R, try to vectorize your operations rather than using loops (which are generally slower in R).

So:

```
E <- 1.655
values <- E*0:(nr-1)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `E*(0:(nr-1))` as the OP wants? Or, `E*1:nr-E`